# How to remove border from python gui

Tags: python-3.x

Hello guys i'm working on a application using python, but i'm having a problem

how can i make a gui window without the default top border which contain the minimize maximize and close icon

using any library(TK, QT5, pygame etc)
pls help as soon as possible

this is my code and i am willing to remove the title bar and just want the frame

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget



class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(MyBar(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(800,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pressing = False


class MyBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        print(self.parent.width())
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title = QLabel("My Own Bar")

        btn_size = 35

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size,btn_size)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        self.btn_min = QPushButton("-")
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        self.btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.title.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_min)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_close)

        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        """)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.parent.width(),
                                self.parent.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        self.parent.close()

    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        self.parent.showMaximized()

    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: help us, help you, please put in some relevant code so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: I just ran your code, and it does not have the default title bar but your custom one - isn't that what you want ?

Comment: no i just made it to show you that i have to remove that thing 
like when we open discord
the loader have no title bar just like that

ithink you are able to understand what am i looking forward to